# .NET vs SQL Server - best practise for repeated searching

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My client is asking for a "suggestion" based lookup to be added to a particular form field.
In other words, as you start typing into a field there should be a "Google style" popup which suggests possible results to select from.  There will be in the order of "tens of thousands" of possible suggestions - this is the best estimate I currently have on the quantity.

Using AJAX to send/retrieve the result, my question is whether it is better to store ALL the suggestions within .NET cache and process there, or whether it's better to run a stored-procedure based query on SQL Server for each request?

This would be using .NET 2.0 and SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bottle neck will be transporting the data from the server to the browser. You can easily produce a large result from the database in almost no time at all, but it takes forever to return to the browser.

You will have to find a way to limit the result that the server returns, so that you only fetch what the user has to see right now.

When you have the data traffic down to reasonable level, you can start looking at optimising the server part. With some caching and logic that should be easy, considering that when the user types the result is often a subset of the previous result, e.g. the match for "hat" is a subset of the match for "ha".

Comment: I think you've hit on a big one here... in particular when people search for a regularly repeated word in the list of suggestions.  Although the caching idea you suggest would increase the users experience, it would required a cache for EACH user on the website, which could increase the server resource requirements even more.

Comment: @freefaller: It wouldn't require a cache for each user, it could just take advantage of how queries often follow each other. It could for example use the cached result for "ha" to produce the result for "hat" without the need to query the database.

Comment: sorry, I must be missing something, because I can't see how it would be any other than user specific.  If multiple users are on the site at the same time (which I would hope they are) then it wouldn't be possible to use a sub-set as the query would most likely be completely different.

Comment: @freefaller: There is no reason to make it user specific. Most of the time the cache would use a previous result from the same user, but if another user is looing for something similar while the result is still in the cache, there is no reason not to use it. Consider for example that the result for "ca" can be used both to produce the result for "car" and "cat".

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and yes I suppose it does make sense to try and store (even for a short amount of time) that sub-set.  Thanks for your input

Answer (score 3):

There is one trick I use every time when faced with such task. Do not do it on every keystroke. Put the launching of the search on a sliding timeout.

The intent here is to launch the search only when the user paused in his/her typing. Usually I set the timeout at .1 to .2 sec. Psychologically it is still instantaneous, but it considerably reduces the load on whatever you will use to search

Comment: I really like this idea, and I will certainly be incorporating it as part of the design... thanks

Comment: that is a great point... And the more I think about it, as a user of Google searches, I end up building a pause in anyway instinctively when typing now. I'll type in what I consider "enough" quickly and then pause ever so slightly to see if "it got it". Feel like a fool when typing in a search box w/o suggest, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

When I've seen the "suggest as you type" type searches done in SQL Server environments, I've seen the best performance using some sort of a caching mechanism, and typically a distributed approach - like a memcached,  typically. Even if your code is optimized well, your database is tuned well and you have your query taking only a <= 10ms with the call to it, process and return, that is still 10ms as they type.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Slightly unclear as to whether you are saying that a 10ms response is a good or bad thing.  I personally wouldn't see a problem with anything under (say) a 500ms response, as it's not exactly critical to be instantaneous

Comment: I was saying sub 10ms would be great but I was using that number to get at the feeling that even great performance out of a DBMS called through the stack can sometimes feel sluggish to users executing a search suggest type search. 10ms was probably the wrong duration to abuse in my example but my point is - I think you'll get faster suggestions with a cache approach. I don't think going SP and optimizing the database/calls for the purpose will be horrible, though, just not -as- fast.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of items. If you can cache the items in a .NET process without running out of memory this will defenitely be faster.

But if that can't be done you are stuck with accessing the database on each request. A stored procedure would be a nice way to do that.

But there are some design patterns which can guide you. I've used the following two while developing something similar to what you are doing.

- [Submission throttling](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Submission_Throttling)
- [Browser side cache](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Browser-Side_Cache)

Comment: Thanks Wouter - this is pretty much exactly the thought patterns I have been going through.  Those two options are certainly something to consider, but I'd be worried about the possible quantity of data to download and store on the browser.

Comment: In the 'dynamic search' app I wrote we limited the maximum number of items do display to something like 10. So for each keystroke we would cache 10 items and when the user typed more characters we could filter the list even more.